# can't add another folder path in environment variables

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I just reinstalled Windows yesterday and I want to set it up again for my needs but why does my enviroment variables look different I didn't add another folder path to the same variables.
how do I add another folder path if the environment variables look like this
[Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3bNp.jpg)

I want it to look like this again [expected appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLvH9.png)
please help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is for _programming_ questions. You might have better luck on [su].